# redirect dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I want to redirect

1)

https://example.com/abc/bluesnrnb-songs-abcd/

https://example.com/abc/bluesnrnb-songs-hgdf/

https://example.com/abc/bluesnrnb-songs-jhgf/

to

https://example.com/abc/blues_n_rnb-songs-abcd/

https://example.com/abc/blues_n_rnb-songs-hgdf/

https://example.com/abc/blues_n_rnb-songs-jhgf/

2)

https://songdew.com/travel/compose-asdf-efgh/222

to

https://example.com/travel/compose_asdf_efgh/222

through htaccess file.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: I want an airplane

Comment: Please check [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why and what you want to do with this urls but maybe you can get the 3th part of url and then redirect with your programing language .

like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^travel/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

if you use `index.php` this will give you `compose-asdf-efgh` and then you can do what ever you want to do with that then redirect .

**Some Tip :**
using `-` is better than using `_` in seo friendly urls , 
as this source said : http://www.ecreativeim.com/blog/2011/03/seo-basics-hyphen-or-underscore-for-seo-urls/